# scp says: Bad configuration option: CheckIP

Tags: scp

I try to do a scp on my centos (without having ever configured anything on the ssh_config) receiving:

```
Bad configuration option: CheckIP
```

Where in ssh_config `CheckIP no` is configured.

Didn't find anything with google, whats up with that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you using wrong directive, try **CheckHostIP** instead of CheckIP

Comment: even though I didn't change anything in the configuration, your answer helped me :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no CheckIP directive. There is a

> **CheckHostIP**
>   If this flag is set to “yes”, ssh(1) will additionally check the host IP address in the known_hosts file.  This allows ssh to detect
>                if a host key changed due to DNS spoofing.  If the option is set to “no”, the check will not be executed.  The default is “yes”.

If you're not specifying this on the command line

```
scp -o checkhostip=no ...
```

then you should look in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for a sitewide default or  `~/.ssh/config` for your local defaults.